# How to personalize XAML Pivot with Path?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to build a pivot control similar to this one, except without the label:

[Microsoft example](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/images/uap_foodtruck_phone_320_tabsboth.png)

In order to do so, I took code from [this page](https://blog.hompus.nl/2015/11/18/highlight-your-selected-pivot-header-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app/) except I don't quite get the animations in XAML.
My problem is, it uses FontIcons and changes the color of the whole header item by animating the Foreground property of a ContentPresenter. I want to use a Path, and don't know how to access the Fill property.

The structure is divided into a TabHeader class containing a RelativePanel with the Path and the label as a TextBlock.

One animation state looks like:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" >
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Icon"
                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" >
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

As you can see, I tried adding an animation state for the icon object, as it is the name of the path in the TabHeader element but this does not work.

EDIT:

Here is the code from the TabHeader class:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="DynamicPivot.TabHeader"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DynamicPivot"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Icon.(RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel)" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="Icon" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith)" Value="Icon" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Icon.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel)" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="Icon" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="Icon" />
                    <Setter Target="RelativePanel.Margin" Value="0,0,12,0"/>
                    <Setter Target="Icon.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <RelativePanel x:Name="RelativePanel">
        <!--<FontIcon x:Name="Icon"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="0,12,0,0"
                  Glyph="{Binding Glyph}"
                  FontSize="16" />-->
        <Path x:Name="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Data="{Binding Glyph}"  Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LabelText"
                   Text="{Binding Label}"
                   Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                   Margin="2,4,2,4" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Show your template where you have your icon/label currently. I'm sure we just need to template bind the property. The default icons all come from font, hence the foreground working. So we just need to open up another property to pass your Fill to the object aka your icon.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the animations into the VisualStateManager like below:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="DynamicPivot.TabHeader"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DynamicPivot"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="Narrow">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Icon.(RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel)" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="Icon" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWith)" Value="Icon" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="500" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="Icon.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel)" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="Icon" />
                    <Setter Target="LabelText.(RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith)" Value="Icon" />
                    <Setter Target="RelativePanel.Margin" Value="0,0,12,0"/>
                    <Setter Target="Icon.Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>

            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Icon" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" >
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <RelativePanel x:Name="RelativePanel">
        <!--<FontIcon x:Name="Icon"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="0,12,0,0"
                  Glyph="{Binding Glyph}"
                  FontSize="16" />-->
        <Path x:Name="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,12,0,0" Data="{Binding Glyph}"  Width="16" Height="16" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="LabelText"
                   Text="{Binding Label}"
                   Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
                   Margin="2,4,2,4" />
    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

Then you will go to the visual state using a call like this:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Selected", false);
```

This should trigger the "Icon"'s fill to SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush.